# Ошибка подключение wiremock

Tags: java, gradle, test-automation, mock

При попытке зупуска сервиса заглушек wiremock, происходит ошибка.

То что пишу в build.gradle

```
dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.17.0"
}
```

Сам класс

```
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.aResponse;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.urlEqualTo;
import static 
 com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options;


public class SampleMock {

public static void main(String args[]){

    WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(8081));
    wireMockServer.start();
    WireMock.configureFor("localhost", wireMockServer.port());

    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/test"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withBody("Hello")));

    wireMockServer.stop();

 }
}
```

И даёт мне ишибку

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/Resources
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.<init>(WireMockConfiguration.java:58)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig(WireMockConfiguration.java:104)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options(WireMockConfiguration.java:108)
    at SampleMock.main(SampleMock.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.Resources
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 4 more
```

Подскажите, в чём дело. Толковых примеров не нашёл. Доккументация, богатая, но не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Нашлась загвостка, нужно было доавить в файл  build.gradle строку с загрузкой зависимостей гугла, так он стал выглядеть.

```
plugins {
id 'java'
}

group 'com.bmw'
 version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile "com.google.guava:guava:27.1-jre"
compile "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.23.2"
}
```